# How to access global variable in Python?

Tags: python, class, methods, global-variables

I have a case :

```
x = "me"

class Test():    
    global x

    def hello(self):
        if x == "me":
            x = "Hei..!"
            return "success"
```

I try this case with shell.

How I can `print x` which the output/value of `x` is `Hei..!`?

I tried with

```
Test().hello # for running def hello
print x # for print the value of x
```

After I print `x`, the output is still `me`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `global x` inside the function not class:

```
class Test():
    def hello(self):
        global x
        if x == "me":
            x = "Hei..!"
            return "success"

Test().hello() #Use Parenthesis to call the function.
```

Don't know why you want to update a global variable from class method, but one another way will be to define `x` as a class attribute:

```
class Test(object): #Inherit from `object` to make it a new-style class(Python 2)
    x = "me"
    def hello(self):
        if self.x == "me":
            type(self).x = "Hei..!"
            return "success"

Test().hello()
print Test.x
```